# No access to server despite setting IP in hosts.allow

Tags: ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, hosts-file, accessibility

I am trying to give a user access to our redhat server from his home computer. I have done this several times for other users already, simply adding the respective IP to the servers hosts.allow file.

The line added to the file looks like this:

```
#Allow access from users home:
sshd: 192.168.1.239 : ALLOW
```

However, when the user tries to login via ssh, he gets:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I have no idea why it is like that. I did some research on this and it appears to be that the users IP is still blocked, despite being listed in hosts.allow. Does someone have any idea what could be the cause of this and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses 192.168.0.0/24  are reserved for users on a local network.

You said from his

> home computer.

I do not think he is connected to your enterprises local network unless via VPN.

Ask him for his real public address

```
curl -4 icanhazip.com
```

then add him to the white list.

Comment: Glad I could be of service!